# Ragged and Jagged Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

What is the difference between ragged and jagged arrays? As per my research both have the same definitions, i.e. two-dimensional arrays with different column lengths.

Comment: As far as I know, it's just two names for the same thing.

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Comment: All right, any reason why different names, could it be programming language specific?

Comment: The only problem with your definition is that ragged/jagged arrays *can* have more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Your question already says the correct answer ^^ but for completeness.*

A Jagged or also called Ragged array is a n-dimensional array that need not the be reactangular means:

```
int[][] array = {{3, 4, 5}, {77, 50}};
```

For more examples you could look [here](http://rommelrico.com/how-to-do-jagged-arrays-in-java/) and [here](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/arrays2.html)!

Comment: could you care to share any links where I can read more about them?

Answer (score 0):

Jagged array is array of arrays such that member arrays can be of different sizes, i.e., we can create a 2-D arrays but with variable number of columns in each row. These type of arrays are also known as ragged arrays.

```
Contents of 2D Jagged Array
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Ragged Array is also known as Jagged Array

1- A jagged array is non uniform array

2- Inner arrays can't be initialized so the following code snippet is going to fail

```
   double[][] jagged = new double[2][3]; //error
```

3- Instead each inner array is initialized separately

```
   double[][] jagged = new double[2][];
   jagged[0] = new double[5];
   jagged[1] = new double[7];
```

Comment: `double[][] jagged = new double[2][3];` is valid Java, isn't it? Do you mean that it's an "error" only in that it isn't a ragged array?

Answer (score -3):

**Ragged array:** is an array with more than one dimension each dimension has different size

ex:

```
10 20 30
11 22 22 33 44
77 88
```

**Jagged array:** an array where each item in the array is another array.
C# Code:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];
jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];
```

Comment: that is not really a difference?

Comment: Then what is the actual difference.