# Store Char array in 2xn Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to understand how `char` stores in `2xn char matrix`

For example

```
 int numWords = in.nextInt();
 char[][] words = new char[numWords][];
```

In above code, `words` is `char` matrx which can store `numWords` number of rows and `n` number of columns in every row. Correct ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
                words[i] = in.next().toCharArray();
                System.out.println("in.next().toCharArray():"+words[i][i]);

            }
```

If I run above code with `numWords` is equals to `1` and having value `a 1`

Then how the `char` array returned by `in.next().toCharArray()` will save into `words` char matrix ?

How matrix will look like ?

Update:

With `numWords` equals to `1`
If an `char array` is having value `a, ,1` and print like this

System.out.println("Values:"+words[i][i] + "------"+words[i][i+1]);

Why its showing below error ? In first row there should be 3 columns ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 1
```

Comment: *How matrix will look like ?* -> print it using `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toDeepString(words));`

Answer (score 1):

Java has no matrix or multidimensional array concept. What you have is an array of arrays, and nothing forces the "internal" arrays to have the same shape (length).

"Array of arrays" means it's an array, where the elements themselves are arrays.

You could visualize the array of arrays like this:

```
0: **********
1: **
2: ******
3: ***************
```

When you write

```
char[][] words = new char[numWords][];
```

you're creating an array, where the elements are arrays of `char`, and initially set to `null`. When you write

```
words[i] = in.next().toCharArray();
```

you're making the array element at index `i` point to a new char array.

Comment: Addition: Arrays which are not rectangular are named [*Jagged arrays*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18269123/5515060), which is the "default" for arrays in java

Comment: it's better to post a new question instead of changing the question to ask something new @maria that way you'll get answers from more people